# Design that I can slide 7 buttons

Tags: html, css

I want to display 7 buttons, but when I use the mobile screen,
I would like to change the layout like the following.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmuJDlgEweM

Below is my current screen

[image]

```css
.discover_history_top {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1E3E75;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.discover_history_btn_collective {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn_discover_history {
  /* margin: 5px; */
  border: solid #1E3E75 !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container condo_container">
  <div class="row mx-auto text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="discover_history_top">
        <div class="discover_history_btn_collective">
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Camera</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Thermostat</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Garage</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Light</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Lock</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Sensor</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Switch</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: look for media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries to overwrite wrapper CSS style (`.discover_history_btn_collective`) for desired break point.

To put elements in one line add `white-space: nowrap;`. In your code I also had to remove flex display from `.discover_history_btn_collective`

```css
.discover_history_top {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1E3E75;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.discover_history_btn_collective {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn_discover_history {
  /* margin: 5px; */
  border: solid #1E3E75 !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  width: 150px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 2500px) {
  .discover_history_btn_collective {
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container condo_container">
  <div class="row mx-auto text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="discover_history_top">
        <div class="discover_history_btn_collective">
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Camera</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Thermostat</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Garage</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Light</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Lock</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Sensor</button>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn_discover_history'>Switch</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```